# Close by or nearby?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, verbs, expression-choice

> The cops traced residential address of his relatives who lived close
>   by.

Close up/down, close off, close in are terms well understood, I have not seen such usage of close + by.

Would it be better to write:

> The cops traced residential address of his relatives who lived nearby.

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Close by/nearby in the sentence implies "close at hand or adjacent".

[near – close](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/near): talking about short distances
If something is near, near to, or close to a place or thing, it is a short distance from it.

When near and close have this meaning, don't use them immediately in front of a noun. Instead use nearby.

- He was taken to a **nearby** hospital.
- He threw the bag into some **nearby** bushes.

  *Nearby, definitely, is more idiomatic than close by.*

Answer (score 0):

Usually, 'Close' is used when the sentence mentions a relationship of some sorts. And 'Near' is usually used in other notions. Although, in most cases these two are interchangeable.

EDIT:

Close By and Nearby however is completely interchangeable.